# Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted (tried to allocate X bytes) in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, server

I am getting this error:

> Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43148176 bytes)

What I am trying to do is on my home page there is popup login form where users login and gets into a 'site/members_area'page. But something very bad is happening with me here after filling up the form when I click on login button. I am getting these errors: firstly maximum execution time limit, after correcting that I get above error increased the memory limit, which is not good practice for good coding.

And even my code doesn't need that much memory - where am I going wrong?
In last after spending huge amount of time after submitting the form I get 500 internal server error? I have already search Stack Overflow for this question but no use?

I am directing my form to my `LoginController` which is

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
print_r( debug_backtrace() );
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000);

class LoginController extends CI_Controller
{

     public function __construct()
     {
          parent::__construct();
          $this->load->library('session');
          $this->load->helper('form');
          $this->load->helper('url');
          $this->load->helper('html');
          $this->load->database();
          $this->load->library('form_validation');

     }

     public function index()
     {
            //load the login model
          $this->load->model('login_model');
          $qry=$this->login_model->validate();

          if($qry) //if user's credentials validated
          {
            $data=array(
                'username'=>$this->input->post('username'),
                'is_logged_in'=>TRUE


            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('site/members_area');
          }
          else {
                $this->index();
          }

     }

}?>
```

My model is:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');



     class Login_model extends CI_Model
        {
             function __construct()
             {
                  // Call the Model constructor
                  parent::__construct();
                  $this->load->database();
             }

             /*//get the username & password from tbl_usrs
             function get_user($usr, $pwd)
             {    
                  $sql = "select * from tbl_usrs where username = '" . $usr . "' and password = '" .$pwd . "' ";
                  $query = $this->db->query($sql);
                  return $query->num_rows();
             }
             */
             function validate() {

                    $this->db->where('username',$this->input->post('username'));
                    $this->db->where('password',md5($this->input->post('password')));
                    $qry=$this->db->get('tbl_usrs');

                    if($qry->num_rows==1)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
             }// function validate ends
        }?>
```

There is no infinite loop and neither I am trying to read any file.

Comment: You've exceeded the amount of available memory in your PHP process. Either increase the amount of memory or make your code more efficient. Since you have had to increase the time-out, it seems like you are trying to do too much work with this script. It doesn't look like it does much though - do you know what part it is getting stuck on?

Comment: (Unsalted MD5 passwords are considered rather insecure these days by the way - don't use this approach if you do not want these passwords to be reversible with a rainbow table).

Comment: ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); it will take unlimited memory usage of server and i have already included in code

Comment: Hmm, try it without quotes. Also, are you on your local dev machine or a remote server? Some configurations prevent access to `memory_limit`, such as on shared hosts.

Comment: i have tried both on local and remote server???

Comment: Ah, I forgot! I don't think you can reset the size of a PHP process after it has started (the RAM has already been allocated by this point). Try resetting it in your `php.ini` and restart your web server.

Comment: increasing the memory limit or execution time does not solve my problem i  set execution time to 300s and memory limit to 128mb after this it keeps processing the form for 5 minutes and give internal server error

Comment: this is something i am getting after 5 minutes 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => C:\xampp\htdocs\ko\system\core\CodeIgniter.php [line] => 408 [function] => require_once ) [1] => Array ( [file] => C:\xampp\htdocs\ko\index.php [line] => 292 [args] => Array ( [0] => C:\xampp\htdocs\ko\system\core\CodeIgniter.php ) [function] => require_once ) ) 
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 619708416) (tried to allocate 65488 bytes)

Comment: That's gone past 619M of RAM, so I think you have a bug. Maybe comment some things out to work out where the issue is. Could the `redirect()` be causing an infinite internal loop?

Comment: Yes, it is redirection loop. Because of at the end of index method you code it wrong way. Pseudo code of your controller/method would look like: `if (anything is wrong and can't pass) {repeat the whole action}`.

Comment: i have worked upon it till now but no success plz any body help in this..

Comment: i don't where i am wrong....

Comment: I don't know CI, but is it normal to do `$this->load->database()` in both the controller and the model? I wonder if it is wrong in the latter, and is causing a loop. Check the docs on this.

Comment: Ah! see @Tpojka's response - that looks absolutely correct.

Comment: @Optimmus You should make redirection to where is login form. It is clear login form and view is not made by this controller. In else state of condition make redirection to that controller/method.

Comment: does this code require this much memory and execution time what u have told @Topjka i have already done it but no success

Comment: do i post post my login form also or any other thing this thing become so much frustating for me

Comment: how can you say that " It is clear login form and view is not made by this controller."

Comment: At least I don't see it. Can you tell the name of view file where login form is? Also code exceeded 32MiB of RAM. Basic Welcome page on fresh CI installation uses less than 2MiB of memory. Check advice from answer bellow.

Comment: @Tpojka you know what you and Anmol made my day you both make my day code below and advice works perfectly this error  is something which can be spotted only  by some experience man.... 
may i can purchase beer for both... :) ;)

Comment: Only if there is one for @halfer too. ;)

Comment: yup absolutely.... :) thank's for your valuable suggestions and ans

Comment: Pleased you've fixed it. Don't forget to fix the MD5 problem - it's not safe as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally this type of occurs when your script is using too much memory. This can often happen in PHP if you have a loop that has run out of control and you are creating objects or adding to arrays on each pass of the loop. Check for infinite loops.

If that isn't the problem, try and help out PHP by destroying objects that you are finished with by setting them to null eg. `$OldVar = null;`.

Check the code where the error actually happens as well. Would you expect that line to be allocating a massive amount of memory? If not, try and figure out what has gone wrong.

@tpojka is right: what is happening is when credentials fails it try to load again your index method and this repeats itself infinity times. You should remove `index();` method and redirect to some other page or echo some statement.

Try something like this:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
print_r( debug_backtrace() );
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000);

class LoginController extends CI_Controller
{

     public function __construct()
     {
          parent::__construct();
          $this->load->library('session');
          $this->load->helper('form');
          $this->load->helper('url');
          $this->load->helper('html');
          $this->load->database();
          $this->load->library('form_validation');

     }

     public function index()
     {
            //load the login model
          $this->load->model('login_model');
        //  $qry=$this->login_model->validate();



          //get the posted values
          $username = $this->input->post("username");
          $password = $this->input->post("password");

          //set validations
          $this->form_validation->set_rules("username", "username", "trim|required");
          $this->form_validation->set_rules("password", "password", "trim|required");

          if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
          {
               //validation fails
             //  $this->load->view('home');
               echo "Validation fails";
          }
          else
          {
               //validation succeeds
               if ($this->input->post('submit') == "Login")
               {
                    //check if username and password is correct
                    $usr_result = $this->login_model->get_user($username, $password);
                    if ($usr_result > 0) //active user record is present
                    {
                         //set the session variables
                         $sessiondata = array(
                              'username' => $username,
                              'loginuser' => TRUE
                         );
                         $this->session->set_userdata($sessiondata);
                         redirect("index/member_area"); //page you want to display for login user only
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Invalid username and password!</div>');
                         redirect('login/index');
                    }
               }
               else
               {
                    redirect('blahhh');
               }
          }
     }

}

?>
```